# How do I convert a single-line JSON file into a human-readable multi-line file?

Tags: json

I am trying to write a script to create JSON files that can be imported into Firefox for bookmarks. In an attempt to examine the structure used by Firefox for bookmarks, I have exported all of my bookmarks to a JSON file.

The problem is that Firefox exports a single-line file (very hard to read). Is there a utility available to convert this file to a readable, indented, multi-line file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use http://jsbeautifier.org for this purpose.

Just copy & paste your JSON into the textarea and then press "Beautify JavaScript or HTML"

Answer (score 0):

Try some online tools such as:
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

simply google "json pretty" :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

That one is a really good online json editor.